Is there an optimal solution for the inverse of the 100 prisoner problem?
There's the famous https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem 100 prisoners problem. There are 100 numbered boxes, each containing the number of one of 100 prisoners. Each prisoner can open 50 out of 100 boxes, and if every last prisoner opens the box with their number in it then they can all go home. If any one prisoner fails then they all fail.
The probability of everyone escaping is ~30% with the optimal solution (open the box with your number on the front, then go to whatever number is inside the box next - creating chains of boxes)
My question - what if the task was for no one to open the box with their number? Only with all 100 people failing can anyone leave?
I ran a simulation and the probability using the standard strategy becomes about 1% that everyone escapes. Is that still the most optimal solution with this set of conditions?
Simulation code if anyone wants to play:
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
new PrisonerProblemHandler(prisonerCount: 100, minChainLength: 51, maxChainLength: 100, logLevel: 0).ProcessMany(10000);

class PrisonerProblemHandler
{
    List<EntityWithNumber> boxes;
    List<int> prisoners;
    int prisonerCount = 100;
    int maxChainLength = 50;
    int minChainLength = 1;
    int logLevel = 1;
    public PrisonerProblemHandler(int prisonerCount = 100, int maxChainLength = 50, int minChainLength = 1, int logLevel = 1)
    {
        this.prisonerCount = prisonerCount;
        this.maxChainLength = maxChainLength;
        this.minChainLength = minChainLength;
        this.logLevel = logLevel;
    }

    public void ProcessMany(int testCount)
    {
        var statuses = Enumerable.Range(0, testCount).Select(result => Escaped()).ToList();
        var successes = statuses.Count(result => result);
        Console.WriteLine($"Tests finished! {successes} out of {statuses.Count} prisoner batches escaped.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Probability: ~{Math.Round(100M * successes / statuses.Count, 2)}%");
    }
    public bool Escaped()
    {
        boxes = Enumerable.Range(0, prisonerCount).Select(boxNumber => new EntityWithNumber()).ToList();
        int boxNum = 0;
        foreach (var prisoner in Enumerable.Range(0, prisonerCount).OrderBy(prisoner => Guid.NewGuid()))
        {
            boxes[boxNum].number = prisoner;
            boxNum++;
        }
        List<List<int>> chains = new List<List<int>>();
        HashSet<int> processedPrisoners = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach (var prisonerNumber in Enumerable.Range(0, prisonerCount))
        {
            if (processedPrisoners.Contains(prisonerNumber))
                continue;
            var prisonerChain = GetChainFromNumber(prisonerNumber, prisonerNumber).ToList();
            chains.Add(prisonerChain);
            foreach (var processedPrisoner in prisonerChain)
                processedPrisoners.Add(processedPrisoner);
        }
        var maxChain = chains.Max(chain => chain.Count);
        var minChain = chains.Min(chain => chain.Count);
        var hasEscaped = maxChainLength >= maxChain && minChainLength <= minChain;

        if (logLevel > 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"Prisoners processed through the system. Chain lengths {minChain}-{maxChain}. {(hasEscaped ? "They escaped!" : "They did not escape.")}");
        if (logLevel > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chains:");
            foreach (var chain in chains.OrderByDescending(chain => chain.Count))
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", chain));
        }
        if (logLevel > 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Boxes: ");
            foreach (var boxIndex in Enumerable.Range(0, prisonerCount))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{boxIndex}:{boxes[boxIndex].number}");
            }
        }
        return hasEscaped;
    }
    private IEnumerable<int> GetChainFromNumber(int seedNum, int activeNum)
    {
        var box = boxes[activeNum];
        yield return box.number;
        if (box.number != seedNum)
            foreach (var chainNum in GetChainFromNumber(seedNum, box.number))
                yield return chainNum;
    }
}
class EntityWithNumber
{
    public EntityWithNumber() { }
    public EntityWithNumber(int boxNum)
    {
        number = boxNum;
    }
    public int number = 0;
}


With the standard strategy, nobody gets their own number precisely when the permutation set by the numbers in the boxes is a $100$-cycle; and the probability of this is exactly $1%$, since the proportion of $n$-cycles among elements of $S_n$ is exactly $1/n$. Of course this doesn't answer the question about other possible strategies.
